# Convert Raw value to voltage in an ADC

Tags: sensor, analog, converter

An ADC (ADS1015 with n=12 bit resolution) is connected to 5V DC power supply. So its V_ref=5V.

However, if I set gain=16, then full-scale-range = +/-0.256V i.e peak to peak voltage= V_pp=2*0.256=0.512V  (as given in data sheet Pg 10, Table 3: Reference https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ads1015.pdf )

In such a scenario, which formula out of the two mentioned below should be used to convert raw data from ADC into equivalent voltage:

(1)       V_in = (Raw data from ADC) * (V_ref/2^n)  = (Raw data from ADC) * (5/4096)

(2)       V_in = (Raw data from ADC) * (V_pp/2^n)   = (Raw data from ADC) * (0.512/4096)

Also, in the above two formula, where do we substitute "gain=16" factor?

If somebody could please explain this I would be very much appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

It’s the second one.  The full range of 4096 counts correspond s to 0.512 volts and so each count corresponds to 0.512/4096 volts.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frog for your comment. ALso, plz let me where do we substitute the "gain=16" factor in this equation?

Comment: Actually the full-scale range with gain = x1 is +/-4.096V, not 5V as you had indicated.  So I think what you’re asking for is V_in = (Raw data from ADC) * (V_pp/2^n) = (Raw data from ADC) * ((8.192 /16)/4096).  Does that make sense?